# What exactly is gsub in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, gsub

I'm still learning Ruby and I'm practicing my `get` routes and `post` requests, User sign in, log in, etc for a basic website and I came across a "slug" method:

```
def slug
    self.username.strip.downcase.gsub(" ","-")
  end
```

I tried using irb to try and figure out what gsub is doing:

```
"hello".gsub(" ","-")
```

but it just gave me:

```
"hello"
```

And I tried using it on a array, but that didn't work as well.

But my question is what exactly is gsub doing here? What is gsub in general? What is the outcome of this method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could explain in detail, what, *precisely* is unclear to you about the documentation. That way, we can avoid a lot wasted time and effort by making sure that we don't repeat something you already know, and equally important that we don't repeat something that you have already read but didn't understand. It is also very important for the Ruby developers to understand why their documentation failed to properly explain the concepts to you, so that they can improve the documentation to prevent future developers from stumbling over the same problems.

Comment: It is also very much unclear what this has to do with ActiveRecord, Sinatra, and Visual Studio Code. Are you writing a VSCode extension in Ruby?

Comment: Someone clearly understood what I was asking. I came to Stack Overflow to ask a simple question and get a simple answer, which happened. I've spent 30 minutes looking at previously asked questions about gsub and NO one had the answers I'm looking for. No gsub isn't something I already know, which is WHY I asked the question. I've tagged ActiveRecord, Sinatra, and VSCode because that's what I'm using for my application. Sorry, didn't know there was a law for the tags I'm supposed to use.

Comment: If I search for questions related to problems with X I do not want to be bothered with Ruby questions.

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation of [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-gsub).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, Gsub is a method that can be called on strings. It replaces all instances of a substring with another one inside the string.

Sub is short for "substitute," and G stands for "global." Think of Gsub like a "replace all" function.

The general pattern is str.gsub("target string", "replacement string").

In your example, nothing changes because there are no spaces in the string "hello" that can be replaced with a "-" character.

```
"hello".gsub(" ","-")
```

The following example replaces the "!" in "hello!" with ", world", printing "hello, world!"

```
puts "hello!".gsub("!",", world!")
```

The following example replaces every instance of "!" in "!!!" with "123", printing "123123123"

```
puts "!!!".gsub("!", "123")
```

Comment: @RoyalTerminal No problem! I've just edited my answer to include a few more examples for you.

Comment: _"It replaces all instances of a substring with another one"_ – yes, but that’s only half the story. You should add an example that uses a _pattern_. Regular expressions is where `gsub` really shines.